# How to get all records in if conditions using Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have two request parameters in array:

```
       {
"users": [1,2,3],
"groups": [1,2]
      }
```

I want to get records of users against id 1,2,4 and groups against id 1,2 I can fetch records of users but I am unable to fetch records of groups.

Here is my code:

```
                       public function isGroupUser(Request $request)
{
    $usersDetail = $request->input('users', []);
    $groupsDetails = $request->input('groups', []);

    if($usersDetail)
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name')
            ->whereIn('users.id',$usersDetail)->get();
        $resultArray = ['users' => $users];

        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }

    elseif ($groupsDetails)
    {
        $groups = DB::table('group')
            ->select('group.id','group.name')
            ->whereIn('group.id',$groupsDetails)->get();
        $resultArray = ['groups' => $groups];

        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }



}
```

I can get the records of users but not getting groups. Where am I wrong?

Currently my JSON response:

```
               {
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    }
]
   }
```

But not getting the groups.

Comment: becasse you use `else if` `elseif ($groupsDetails)`, meaning only the `if` part of your code executes

Answer (score 0):

You got some problems

1. You are replacing `resultArray` when you are trying to assign groups to it,
2. You are writing elseif condition which suggest, only one of two condition will always satisfy

Change these two lines

```
$resultArray['users'] = $users; // here result array will have key users 

$resultArray['groups'] = $groups; // here result array will have key groups
```

`elseif ($groupsDetails)` replace this with `if($groupsDetails)`

In above case, its pushing data into array. In your case its replacing array.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like below,

in your code only one part (either `if` or `elseif`) works

```
    $usersDetail = $request->input('users', []);
    $groupsDetails = $request->input('groups', []);
    $resultArray = []; // an empty array to store your results

    if($usersDetail)
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name')
            ->whereIn('users.id',$usersDetail)->get();
        $resultArray['users'] = $users;


    }

    if ($groupsDetails)
    {
        $groups = DB::table('group')
            ->select('group.id','group.name')
            ->whereIn('group.id',$groupsDetails)->get();
        $resultArray['groups'] = $groups;


    }
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove first return. because if in request have user then when got to return  and then get out from if anad not get to second return.

edited: @Shobi answered well